# ESAPI4PHP vs Codeigniter Built-in Security

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have one project that is using ESAPI4PHP which is a port of OWASP's ESAPI.  I am starting another project using Code Igniter and I notice that they have built-in security controls (form validation, etc...).  Has anybody used both?  If so, which would you choose again?

Comment: Neither. But the CI filter methods look pretty solid and useful. What advantages does ESAPI have in your opinion? Judging from the documentation it seems somewhat shallow, yet fiddly.

Comment: I've looked pretty extensively at CI's XSS filtering method and have found it to be fairly thorough. A few months back, I tried (and failed) to find any known security flaws therein.

Comment: Thanks for the comments guys.  I'll admit that the docs aren't very thorough, but it is extensible and covers all the bases that OWASP covers.  If you're familiar with RSnake, he has a great XSS primer (http://ha.ckers.org/xss.html).  ESAPI protects against all of that.  I don't know about Code Igniter, but if it looks solid, I'll definitely give it a go.

Comment: No experience with ESAPI4PHP, but I've had no problems developing larger security-conscious applications with CI's validation tools (also in combination with jQuery for user experience).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would definitely go for Codeigniter simply for the vastly superior user base and documentation. If it is security that is your only concern then the popularity does mean that Codeigniter is constantly under public scrutiny for security holes that would be quickly fixed. ESAPI is great for XSS and a tonne of exploits but you'll probably find that Codeigniter is equally well equipped.

Still no 'comment on anything' privs so sorry about the answer where a comment would do!